# Append divs while sorting them on the fly

Tags: javascript, html

I have some Json data that I receive from a server via Comet, this data comes in chunks, each chunk has a particular ID, let's say: a, b, c and d.

These chunks come in a random order, so the chunk 'a' could actually be received second, 'd' first, etc...

These chunks, after being formatted as HTML, are appended to a container. What I need is the following: No matter in what order these chunks arrive, I need them to be appended to the container in the correct alphabetical order of their IDs, this will lead to the following div:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="chunk" id="a">...</div>
   <div class="chunk" id="b">...</div>
   <div class="chunk" id="c">...</div>
   <div class="chunk" id="d">...</div>
</div>
```

A solution would be to wait for all the chunks to be received then appending them in the correct order but this breaks one requirement I have, that as soon as a chunk is received it should be displayed.

Is there any way of appending the divs while making sure the correct order is kept?

Comment: What about looping throug all your chunk divs from top to bottom if you have something with "c" and you appended "a, f" you know you can add it after "a" and before "f"

Comment: Would be easiest if you _had_ the div elements already there in the first place, and just filled the data _into_ them. (Or _replace_ initially existent elements with the received div elements, if you have to insist on getting whole divs from the server.)

Comment: Seems like a great time to use [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore). When you get a new chunk, go down the list in order until you find an item that should come after the current inserting item, and do `container.insertBefore(tooFarElement, newElement)`.

Comment: @CBroe and apsillers, I like both your solutions, I'm going to try them out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could just append the new content and then sort the elements

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'page.php'
}).done(function(chunk) {
    $('#container').append(chunk)

    $('#container .chunk').sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.id.localeCompare(b.id);
    }).appendTo('#container');
});
```